# Can anyone tell my how I can fix my model (Using FluentAPI) so that I can assign a different User to my User.FriendCollection?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-5

I am new to CodeFirst and I am trying to create a Friends Collection so that two Users can have each other in their Friends Collection.

Here is my User Class:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        if (FriendCollection == null) FriendCollection = new Collection<Friend>();
    }
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Friend> FriendCollection { get; set; }
}

public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.ID);
    }
}
```

Here is my Friend Class:

```
public class Friend
{
    public Friend()
    {
        DateAdded = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public long UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class FriendConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Friend>
{
    public FriendConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.ID);
        HasRequired(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.FriendCollection).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserID);
    }
}
```

Here is my Entity Class:

```
    public Entities()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Entities>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Entities>());
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Friend> Friends { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FriendConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And here is my Console Code and ideally what I would like to achieve:

```
        using (Entities db = new Entities ())
        {
            var u1 = new User();
            db.Users.Add(u1);

            var u2 = new User();
            db.Users.Add(u2);

            u1.FriendCollection.Add(new Friend { User = u2 });
            u2.FriendCollection.Add(new Friend { User = u1 });

            try
            {
                var cnt = db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
```

SaveChanges throws an error whenever I tried to populate the Friend class with a User object saying:

> > Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Friend_User_Target' of the relationship 'Entities.Friend_User' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

If I assign to the UserID like this:

> > u1.FriendCollection.Add(new Friend { UserID = u2.ID });

This allows me to save the entities, but not correctly!

When I step through the code I can isolate the problem and here's what I find:

```
b.FriendCollection.Add(new Friend { UserID = a.ID });
//Friend.UserID = 1
db.SaveChanges();
//Friend.UserID = 2 matching the b.ID
```

So now I can go back to my previous example and SaveChanges() without throwing the error if I assign the Friend.User to the calling User.  For example:

```
b.FriendCollection.Add(new Friend { User = b }); 
db.SaveChanges()
```

But when I try to assign a different user I get the error.  For example:

```
b.FriendCollection.Add(new Friend { User = a }); 
db.SaveChanges()
```

I get:

> > Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Friend_User_Target' of the relationship 'Entities.Friend_User' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

Can anyone tell my how I can fix my model (Using FluentAPI) so that I can assign a different User to my User.FriendCollection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping is not correct, at least not correct for the meaning of the relationships in your model.

Your mapping creates one single relationship and the two navigation properties `User.FriendCollection` and `Friend.User` are the two ends of this single relationship. You have defined them as inverse properties.

But this would mean that if you have a user UserA who has a FriendB in the `FriendCollection` the `User` in FriendB must be UserA and not any other user. Your model can only express that a user is a friend of him/herself, so to speak. Because you are adding another user to the collection you get exceptions.

In my opinion the entity `Friend` does not represent a friend = another user, but it actually expresses a relationship. It's kind of an intermediate entity for a many-to-many relationship between users and this relationship is a `Friendship` (I would prefer to call it this way.)

In any case your model needs two relationships. You can leave the entities as they are but use this mapping:

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.ID);
        HasMany(x => x.FriendCollection)
            .WithRequired();
    }
}

public class FriendConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Friend>
{
    public FriendConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.ID);
        HasRequired(x => x.User)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

(Disabling cascading delete on one of the relationships is necessary to avoid the infamous "multiple cascading delete path exception".)

Note that you have now two foreign keys in the `Friend` table, `UserID` for the second and `User_ID` for the first mapping. You can rename the default column name by adding `Map(m => m.MapKey("SomeUserID"))` to the first mapping.

With this mapping your console code should work.

Comment: Yes you are correct... My model is self-referencing which is NOT what I want it to do.  BTW: Updating the relationship mappings does NOT fix the issue.  I still get the Multiplicity constraint violation.  **How should the model look so I can achieve the desired result as defined in my console code?**

Comment: @user1265146: Nothing to change in your model, just replace the mapping code as shown in my answer. If it doesn't work can you please check carefully if you have used *exactly* the code above. I've tested the code now and it works as I said. BTW: Are you really using EF 5 beta (as your tag indicates) or EF 4.X? (I've tested with EF 4.1.)

Comment: I'm using EF5b1.  Yes I just changed the mappings (or added a mapping to UserConfiguration) and added the CascadeDelete(false) to the FriendConfiguration.  Can we meet in chat?

Comment: @user1265146: **Did you also REMOVE the lambda expression from `WithMany`**? It's very important! If it doesn't work we can meet in chat :)

Comment: Yes.. That was it.. Thank-you!  The WithMany lambda was the culprit.

Comment: @user1265146: OK, then I'm happy that EF 5 doesn't introduce a nasty bug.